# send email with user input from react native app to an email address

Tags: ios, react-native, user-input

I'm creating a simple pharmacy app that allows users to fill/refill their prescriptions so the pharmacists can prepare them ahead of them arriving. but i can't for the life of me find a way to send the user inputs to an email address without going through the email app. if thats not possible what are some other ways of sending the data ?

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can send an email directly from the react-native app. You need an email server to send emails. An example is [SendPulse](https://sendpulse.com) or [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/)

You can then send a POST request from your react-native app to their API

Comment: thanks Utsu! if i don't want to go the email route whats another possible way to get the info to the pharmacists ?